# Replace appcache with ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache, service-worker

OK, so I tried to [replace](https://gitlab.com/mcepl/zalmy/commit/1b8dc04a974ce95cdd80abd3e16163162596a48b) `appcache` with `ServiceWorker` in my simple webapp, but when trying in Chromium with switched off networking, I get "Page cannot be downloaded").

Anybody know why? Any simple HOWTO for replacing Application cache with ServiceWorker-based system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the development webserver I used. It was apparently serving old files. Once restarted, everything works fine. Thank you.